# Flowable.parallel vs Flowable.flatMap?

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

RxJava 2.0.5 introduced the `ParallelFlowable` type, corresponding to the `Flowable.parallel()` operator. I've found that the general advice for achieving parallelism is with `flatMap` like so:

```
Flowable.just(1,2,3)
    .flatMap(x -> Flowable.just(x)
        .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
        .map(y -> y + 1))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

When is it appropriate to use `flatMap` for parallelism, and when is it better to use `ParallelFlowable`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I've found that the general advice for achieving parallelism is with flatMap like so:

Those advises come from before the introduction of `parallel` so API evolution since then should be considered.

> When is it appropriate to use flatMap for parallelism, and when is it better to use ParallelFlowable?

`ParallelFlowable` has a limited set of operators: `map`, `filter`, `doOnNext`, `reduce`, `flatMap`, etc. instead of the full blown `Flowable` API. Thus if you have something "exotic" to do in parallel which can't be expressed with the operators above, you should stick to `Flowable.flatMap` based parallelism (or consider `groupBy` parallelism).

Otherwise, [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/pull/4974#issuecomment-272805695) is a benchmark comparison between the parallelization approaches ([code](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/2.x/src/perf/java/io/reactivex/parallel/ParallelPerf.java#L67)).

Comment: So reasonable general advice is "use `ParallelFlowable` when its operations are sufficient, otherwise use `flatMap` or `groupBy`? Thanks!